# Android self-updating ui page

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm very new to Android. I'm just wondering if this is possible on Android. I'm displaying values that are being pulled from a server. These values are getting updated every 30 secs. I wanted to update/refresh my Android UI page every 30 sec also to display the current values. I'm using 3.0 if it makes any difference.

Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: You can use threads to update the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Task is simple. Launch an AsyncTask every 30 seconds and then update the ui using direct method invocation or handlers to update the ui.

Read about Handlers [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).
Example of AsyncTask - [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).